# android: Device's GPU/CPU overloaded on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overloading, gpu

There's something I absolutely cannot explain or understand.
My App uses RecyclerView (it is a shopping list). On a MOTO G5S with Android 7.1.1, the app works fine. Recently, on a second G5S I accepted the update to 8.1.0 and my app does not work any more. This is how it looks like when the app is started:

[image: app started]

And here is what happens when I try to swipe away an item.

[image: swiping away]

Swiping away goes extremely slow and the three dot menu in the top right corner opens very slow too.

The same app installed on Moto G5S with Android 7.1.1 works very fine and looks like this:
[image]

Of course, there are some overdraws but eliminating them did not make things noticeable better. I have no idea of what is going wrong here. On Android 9 and Galaxy S9, the app works but, of course, it is a really powerfull device which should not be comared here. Other apps with lists (WhatsApp, GoogleMail and so on) work without big difference. Does anybody have any idea what's the matter here?

EDIT:
Running Android Studios Profiler, I could see that a device with Android 7.1.1 needs much less cpu time than one with Android 8.1.
[image: Android 8.1]

[image: Android 7.1.1]

Comment: Try a factory reset on the updated phone and reinstall the app.  I had poor performance issue with updating OnePlus3 7.1 to 8.0. A factory reset solved the issue.

Comment: Since it only did it on the device after the device update then I suspect the device update has an issue of which it will have many bugs anyway. If it were something like the cpu being underpowered then both would have the problem. Of course maybe it's a problem with the RecyclerView code and the version used so you could try another. Maybe something else. But I've used RecyclerView for 2 years or so and didn't notice any performance problems on multiple devices.